# .php files are downloaded instead of displayed

Tags: nginx, fpm, php-7.3

First of all, yes there are lots of questions like these but none of the solutions worked for me.
I have a similar server to compare to and I looked at the configs and it seems to work, whereas this new setup doesn't.

I already tried mendling with the configs without any prevail.

My nginx.conf:

```
[default content]
#I just appended this line:
client_max_body_size 10M;
```

My virtual host file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

#    root /var/www/mywebsite.com/public_html;

 #   index index.html;

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

   # access_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.com.access.log;
   # error_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.com.error.log;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   # location / {
   #     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;


    root /var/www/mywebsite.com/public_html;
    index index.php;
    # . . . other code

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
 }

#location / {
#        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
#}
#location ~ \.php$ {
#        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/wordpress)(/.*)$;
#}

include snippets/phpmyadmin.conf;
}
```

P.S Yes, I am using WordPress.

Comment: This is in Safari?

Comment: It is browser independant.

Comment: It is clearly an issue with nginx and or PHP and not the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that it was just a cache issue so I had to wait and it worked afterwards. The config is OK. Case closed.